# Circular arrangement with consecutive numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Five persons are to be seated around a circular table they are wearing badges of consecutive numbers 1,2,3,4,5. In how many ways can they be seated such that no two consecutive numbered badge wearing people are seated next to each other ?

My attempt:
I got only 2 cases

1. 13524
2. 14253

But the answer is 10.

Comment: You can rotate your solutions in steps of $72^\circ$

Comment: I think the answer is wrong , i just drew all possible arrangements , and verified these are the only 2 correct . May be question language is the problem

Comment: @Hagen von Etizen : in circular arrangement does sitting arrangement matters , don't we assume all sits identical?

Comment: But should the answer be 2 then? After persons are seated do we count different starting points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, $13524$ and $35241$ are to be counted as different seating arrangements, if we are to get to a count of $10$.  So it seems that we are to count differing starting points as different seating arrangements.

This means your two solutions each become five by rotating the starting point.

Why do I not think there are more seating arrangements?  $3$ cannot be adjacent to $2$ or $4$.  Therefore, $3$ and its neighbors must be $135$ or $531$.  Since $2$ cannot be next to $1$ and $4$ cannot be next to $5$, we have $41352$ and $25314$.  (In both cases, we create the allowed adjacency between $2$ and $4$.)  These are the Question's two answers, but with rotated starting points.